# What did Musk mean by this Chinese comment?

Tags: meaning-in-context, idiom-request, offensive-language

In [a comment](https://twitter.com/elonmusk/status/1578049022102851584) to Hu Xijin's Tweet, Musk said that:

> 手整体插在口袋里的人过分自信

It seems like a saying translated from another language, but so far as I know not from Chinese (Confucius did not say that), then I wonder if there exists an English idiom equivalent or not?

Literally, it means *Man with hands in pockets feels cocky all day*, but [this source](https://twitter.com/sunnylqm/status/1578208635066679297) [is said](https://news.yahoo.com/elon-musk-gotten-twitter-brawl-055442710.html?guccounter=1&guce_referrer=aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbS8&guce_referrer_sig=AQAAAE0wOxJuv5bYU8Qkn_i8U5Z9M1qmmNTsqnsnZDz4LZsJmXyax5orfTuqksbO2gBJvDM0Th7ewNplyumZP08PdnJVyF8rSvRNTCc4GCs93S1BnYL5mK8H0dRtNfAvhHrzJyx6Nf9nS5fNkFKPgdTL7RZ6f0DNiJin_lSjtN9ZGOoI) to be fake. <del>I learned that in America *Confucius say* amounts to *Lu Xun say* in China.</del> (We mean dogmatic when we say *Lu Xun say*, but here *Confucius say* is offensive in this scenario).

And in my opinion, it means that Hu lacks hands-on experience and looks unrealistic and overconfident, but [it is said that](https://shorturl.at/fkBCM) most Chinese interpret it wrongly(I have watched tens of Chinese videos and many tweets on Weibo interpreting this sentence and all of them are about 'unrealistic but overconfident') and I don't know what the meaning would be:

1. What is the original saying? I am uncertain about it for two reasons: a) the original saying is ungrammatical; b) [the article](https://news.yahoo.com/elon-musk-gotten-twitter-brawl-055442710.html?guccounter=1&guce_referrer=aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbS8&guce_referrer_sig=AQAAAE0wOxJuv5bYU8Qkn_i8U5Z9M1qmmNTsqnsnZDz4LZsJmXyax5orfTuqksbO2gBJvDM0Th7ewNplyumZP08PdnJVyF8rSvRNTCc4GCs93S1BnYL5mK8H0dRtNfAvhHrzJyx6Nf9nS5fNkFKPgdTL7RZ6f0DNiJin_lSjtN9ZGOoI#:%7E:text=an%20innuendo%2Dladen-,fake%20Confucius%20quote,-that%20states%3A%20%22Man) says it is *fake Confucius quote*. I didn't get the point of *fake Confucius quote*.
2. If the original saying is *Man with hands in pockets feels cocky all day*, what does it mean in this context?

Comment: One perceives a poor pun in that meme translation... He's trolling him with a stupid meme.

Comment: @LukeSawczak Is the meme [this one](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/614455-confucius-say-man-with-hand-in-pocket-feel-cocky-all)? But it seems ungrammatical. It seems very wellknown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'joke', if it even deserves that title, is somewhat racist (against Chinese), in that it assumes that Chinese people (even Confucius!) speak or spoke a kind of pidgin or broken English, lacking all articles, and often with incorrect pronouns, e.g. 'him' instead of 'he', and wrong verb forms. They used to be common in my youth in Britain, especially on 'seaside postcards'. The point of the alleged humour is double meaning. Below is one I found:

[image]

One I remember from my youth had a similar picture, of a woman in a bikini, with men looking appreciatively, and the caption was 'Confucius him wise man. He say: woman who wear bikini become public figure'.

The one about the hands in the pocket relies on the fact that a slang word for 'penis' is 'cock', so that the man either feels 'cocky' (conceited or confident in a bold or cheeky way) all day, or (the double meaning) feels his own penis all day. This is the sort of joke that immature boys aged about 13 laugh at. For an adult to make such a joke about another could be a deliberate insult. Possibly, Musk is suggesting sarcastically that Hu Xijin (figuratively) only makes love to himself (or his own hand), and is, hence, impervious to the views of others. Or, more simply, that Musk is calling Hu Xijin an impudent chronic masturbator?

Comment: Your explanation, especially the last sentence, aligns more well with what many Chinese think of Hu(as well). Point taken.

Answer (score 2):

Confucius definitely did not say that. It's a vulgar pun based on the fact the English word "cock" can mean penis. That is, the man in the saying is [touching himself](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/touch+himself) (a taboo thing, especially to do it "all day"). It's being used to insult Hu Xijin's confidence (*cocky* means confident).

Assuming that the original phrasing is "man who feel…" this is also using bad grammar on purpose, as is typical in (usually older) stereotyped depictions of Chinese people, like [Charlie Chan](https://blog.adw.org/2012/03/100-charlie-chan-sayings-and-proverbs-a-surprisingly-good-selection-of-truisms-and-insights-for-your-reading-pleasure/) ("[nuggets of fortune cookie Confucius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charlie_Chan)" is a good way to describe it).

In any case, Musk didn't invent the quote; it appears on other, older lists of [fake Confucius quotes](https://www.cs.hmc.edu/%7Eivl/writing/quotes/confucious) in one form or another. These aren't things that people usually say to one another (unless, I suppose, you want something markedly "Chinese" to insult a Chinese person with).

Comment: Get it. I was wrong 

Comment: But the Chinese version failed to convey the key point.

Comment: @LernerZhang: there are many languages and cultures where the penis is compared to a rooster (indeed the English word “rooster” was purported coined to replace “cock”, which had become almost universal English slang for penis), and/or where is a rooster is a symbol of arrogance, but apparently Chinese is not among them.

Comment: @MichaelLorton The key words in that sentence are "feel" and "cocky", but in the Chinese version both are missing.

Comment: @MichaelLorton In Chinese, "大公鸡"(cock) is also related to "penis".

Comment: @LernerZhang — Musk used 过分自信 to mean “feel cocky”, either not realizing that the pun would be lost or counting on it, insulting Hu in a way that other people would understand but Hu would not.  Musk is a bright guy, so my money is on the latter.

Comment: @MichaelLorton I don't know if Hu has understood the pun but most Chinese have not. They comprehend it as "Hu is unrealistic but confident". I think you are right. Hu has also been insulted so much in China.

Comment: @LernerZhang — I think that makes it funnier, Hu thinking he has been praised as exuding confidence while in fact he has been called an incessant masturbator, and perhaps Musk does too.

Comment: @MichaelLorton I think you are right, refer to this tweet by Hu: https://twitter.com/HuXijin_GT/status/1578224761288941568

Comment: The Charlie Chan and similar films had a lot of stereotypes, including ad hoc ancient Chinese proverbs, but they weren't all one-sided: *“What’s all this?”
— “The sarcophagus from the Chinese tomb, sir, that once contained the body of a Ming emperor.”
— “They tell me that a Chinese archaeological expedition is digging up the body of George Washington in exchange.”
— “Sir?”*
 —  [Phantom of Chinatown (1940)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fm5t5UylSHc&t=2440s&ab_channel=TimelessClassicMovies).